# Django log errors and traceback in file in production environment

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new working with logging in django, I'm making a production deployment (DEBUG=False) of an app but I'm not allowed to use any error tracker like Sentry to catch possible problems, so I was wondering if it's possible to log the traceback or part of it in production environment to a file using a logger.

I made something like this in my production settings:

```
import logging.config
# Clear prev config
LOGGING_CONFIG = None

# Get loglevel from env
LOGLEVEL = os.getenv('DJANGO_LOGLEVEL', 'debug').upper()

logging.config.dictConfig(
        {
            'version': 1,
            'disable_existing_loggers': False,
            'filters': {
                'require_debug_false': {
                    '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
                },
                'require_debug_true': {
                    '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
                },
            },

            'handlers': {
                'console': {
                    'level': 'INFO',
                    'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                },
                'file': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                    'filename': 'debug.log',
                },
            },
            'loggers': {
                "": {
                    "level": "ERROR",
                    "handlers": ["console", "file"],
                },

                'django': {
                    'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'propagate': True,
                },
                'django.request': {
                    'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
                    'propagate': True,
                    'level': 'ERROR',
                },
            }
        }
    )
```

But the only thing I got on debug.log is:

```
Internal Server Error: /job/create/
Internal Server Error: /job/create/
Internal Server Error: /job/create/
```

Logs to file without any other information, I would like to have some meaningful information in debug.log to have a clue where can be the error, this is something what I would like to get:

```
[2021-07-27 23:47:29 +0000] [ERROR] Internal Server Error: /job/create/ 
AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
jobs/views.py in CreateJob at line 29
[2021-07-27 23:49:18 +0000] [ERROR] Internal Server Error: /job/create/ 
AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'
jobs/views.py in CreateJob at line 29
```

There is a way to achieve that with logging? Or how can I get a traceback or a resume of the traceback in case of possible errors in production environment without services like Sentry?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a logging format and add that to your handler.

For your example this could look like:

```
'formatters': {
    'mystyle': {
        'format': u'%(asctime)s %(levelname)-6s %(lineno)-4s%(name)-15s %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%H:%M:%S',
    },
'handlers': {
    'console': {...},
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': 'debug.log',
        'format': 'mystyle',
    },
},
```

The formatter is defined in an own section to make it reusable. I.e. multiple handlers could use the same formatter.
A list of what you can use as placeholders in your format can be found here (I think there is something like stack trace as well):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Answer (score 0):

After some grilling and trial and error, this is my settings for logging debuug and error logs. This settings has the following:

1. Captures error logs in a separate file with a formatter that gets the details.
2. Captures complete traceback if there is a 500 error.
3. Captures all 4XX errors.
4. Captures debug logs in its own file.

In settings.py file:

```
# Logging settings
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "require_debug_false": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse",
        },
        "require_debug_true": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue",
        },
    },
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "{name} {levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d",
            "style": "{",
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "[{asctime}] [{levelname}] [{module}] > {message}",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d: %H:%M:%S",
            "style": "{",
        },
        "with_error_detail": {
            "format": "[{asctime}] [{module}] > {message} >> {exc_info}",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d: %H:%M:%S",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
        "file_debug": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs/debug.log",
            "formatter": "simple",
        },
        "file_error": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "logs/error.log",
            "formatter": "with_error_detail",
            "level": "WARNING",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": os.getenv("DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL", "INFO"),
        },
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["file_error"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": False,
            # "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
        },
        "meetings": {
            "handlers": ["file_debug"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "users": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}
```

Here's a sample of some logs captured (I am showing a part of the traceback here..):

```
[2023-08-15: 01:04:01] [ERROR] [log] > Internal Server Error: /api/users/register/user/
[2023-08-15: 01:04:20] [ERROR] [log] > Internal Server Error: /api/users/register/user/
[2023-08-15: 23:54:01] [log] > Internal Server Error: /api/users/register/user/ >> None
[2023-08-16: 00:06:43] [log] > Bad Request: /api/users/register/user/ >> None
[2023-08-16: 00:16:52] [log] > Unauthorized: /api/users/user/1234/ >> None
[2023-08-16: 00:17:19] [log] > Not Found: /api/meeting/timings/4699/ >> None
[2023-08-16: 00:17:54] [log] > Not Found: /api/meeting/timing/4699/ >> None
[2023-08-16: 00:20:34] [log] > Internal Server Error: /api/users/register/patient/ >> (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserRegisterSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'email'."), <traceback object at 0x00000240E8A48500>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\my-django-project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 446, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File "C:\Projects\my-django-project\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 96, in get_attribute
```